# Installing Built in JPG encoder Windows Server 2003 Web edition

Tags: c#, windows-server-2003, codec, encoder

I have a service running on my server that needs to use a JPG encoder. Unfortunately I have found that my Windows Server 2003 does not have a JPG encoder. I was wondering whether it was possible to install one? http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=32 Is this the correct install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Server 2003 infact has a built in jpg encoder. Installing that update doesn't fix anything. The problem is it has a different WIC to what windows 7/8 use and cannot be updated. So when you deploy your service that worked in localhost to a windows server 2003. The server throws a notfoundexception.